# How to extract the subscript from a variable?

Tags: equation-solving, subscript

I simply want to be able to assign the subscript from something like Subscript[x, 1] to a new variable. How should I do this?

Comment: The question is not really clear. An example would help.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a variable

```
y=Subscript[x, 1];
```

then to extract the index it suffices to do

```
y[[2]]
```

which in this case returns 1 as expected.

For more than one indices, this works

```
In[1]:= y=Subscript[x,1,2,3]
Out[1]= Subscript[x,1,2,3]

In[2]:= y[[2;;-1]]/.Subscript->List
Out[2]= {1,2,3}
```

Answer (score 1):

For `y` with any number of subscripts ,

```
Rest[List @@ y]
```

also works.  For instance

```
y = Subscript[x, 1, 2];
Rest[List @@ y]
(* {1, 2} *)
```

As a word of advice, use `Subscript` and the like for formatting expressions for display but not for symbolic computations, where it sometimes leads to problems.